# React screen position after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why the screen stays scrolled after render another content? And how to render inatntly on top of the page when I have a lot of content on my page?

```
useEffect(() => {
     window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
     })
 }, []);
```

it's good but delayed and I want to render instant on top without any movement. I think it's common problem but for no reason I can't find answer.

Comment: try changing `smooth` to `instant`

Answer (score 0):

There is no much details on your question but if you want to update your view before rendering and synchronously, you should use **useLayoutEffect** instead of **useEffect**

1. State changed (new content), render triggered
2. React renders your component
3. ***useLayoutEffect runs (scrolling to top in your case), and React waits for it to finish before do the painting of your screen***
4. Screen is updated